# Unable to get email cache on mail clients on raring ringtail

Tags: 13.04, email

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail.

When I try to send an email my email cache does not show email addresses of the people I have sent emails to before which is annoying cause I have to type the whole email address every time for each person I need to send the email to.

Tried Thunderbird and Evolution.

Is there any way I can get this fixed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling "Automatically add outgoing e-mail addresses to my:" form Composition settings in Thunderbird?

Open up Thunderbird, click on the app menu (the three dashes) and then "Settings" now in "Composition" tab enable "Automatically add outgoing e-mail addresses to my:".

With this feature every time you send an email Thunderbird adds the email address inside the address book.

Comment: I'll try that out.